# CSS Layout Issue - Div not extending with content

Tags: css, html

I am new to DIV layouts and working with CSS so please forgive me if I don't make sense with what I'm  about to ask.

**Issue**
I have a page that if everything is blank the page renders correctly with my divs filling up the screen. When I tested a situation where the content was larger than the content area the content div did not expand in height with the content. I have worked on this for a couple of hours but can't seem to get it to work. Below is what my CSS Sheet looks like. Any guidance you can give will be greatly appreciated.

**Ideal Fix**
Header section is always at the top at 100px, the SubMenu section is always under the header at 50px, the footer is always at the bottom of the page at 50px and the content section is always between the SubMenu and footer section. If the content doesn't fill the page the content section fills the rest of the page so the footer is at the bottom and if the content is larger than the page the content section pushes the footer down the screen to fill all the content in. (Hope that makes sense)

I webpage has the following divs in it.

```
Div 1 - container
Div 2 - Header
Div 3 - SubMenu
Div 4 - Content
Div 5 - Footer
```

**CSS Sheet**

```css
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #7EB5D6;
}

.container {
    width: 700px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
}

.Header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: lightpink;
    position: relative;
}

.SubMenu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: darkgray;
    position: relative;
}

.Content {
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 200px);
    background-color: wheat;
    position: relative;
}

.Footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    position: inherit;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put your content height:auto so that it can be auto adjust according to content.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me after I made another modification. I noticed if I changed height to auto and then had no content the div didn't appear at all so I added min-height: calc(100% - 200px); with the height: auto; and that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the clearfix method!  It works like a charm!

Add this to your css somewhere:

```
.clearfix:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Then add `clearfix` as a second class to all appropriate divs!

Comment: I tried this and for some reason it didn't work for me. I added it to the bottom of my CSS sheet and started with adding clearfix to my content div (class="Content clearfix") but the 1000px height table I put in the page extended past the footer. I then added clearfix to all my other divs but the issue still happens. I will continue to play with just in case I missed something. I want to make sure I give you create for finding the fix if I can get it to work.

Comment: Ok :)  Without seeing your html I couldn't know if this would work for sure.  However, this often fixes many issues where a div doesn't acknowledge its content.  Keep it handy!  BTW: you did implement it correctly too!